# Duvida sobre leitura de codigo em C

Tags: c, lógica

Tenho uma duvida sobre um codigo que fiz em C, o enunciado é o seguinte:

"Escrever um algoritmo em C que leia o Preço de uma mercadoria e exiba o preço na tela reajustado
de 3%. O usuário escolherá a Opção: (A)créscimo ou (D)esconto para o reajuste de 3 %. Agora Faça agora o mesmo exercício, entretanto; lendo o reajuste (em %) do usuário."

A primeira parte consegui resolver, porem na segunda (quando tenho que definir se o usuario escolhera o valor da porcentagem ou o programa seguira normalmente conforme o enunciado) estou tendo problemas, pois quando executo, o programa pergunta se quero escolher o valor do desconto pedindo pra eu digitar 'YES' ou 'NOT' se eu não quiser, só que assim que digito YES ou NOT, ele pergunta se eu quero adicionar ou remover e logo em seguida o programa se encerra com o return 0, ou seja, ele não entra no if e nem nos switchs, gostaria de esclarecer essa duvida, obrigado!

Segue o codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float productPrice, reajustedPrice, percentageValue;
    char switchChoose, operationChoose;

    printf("if you want to add the percentage value type YES if not type NOT\n");
    scanf("%c", &operationChoose);

    if (operationChoose == 'YES')
    {
        printf("Enter percentage value\n");
        scanf("%f", &percentageValue);

        printf("A to Addition\nD to Descount\n");
        scanf("%c", &switchChoose);

        switch (switchChoose)
        {
        case 'A':
            printf("Entering case A...\n");
            printf("Enter product price:\n");
            scanf("%f", &productPrice);

            reajustedPrice = productPrice + (productPrice * (percentageValue / 100));
            printf("Total price: %.2f", reajustedPrice);
            break;

        case 'D':
            printf("Entering case D...\n");
            printf("Enter product price:\n");
            scanf("%f", &productPrice);

            reajustedPrice = productPrice - (productPrice * (percentageValue / 100));
            printf("Total price: %.2f", reajustedPrice);
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("A to Addition\nD to Descount\n");
        scanf("%c", &switchChoose);

        switch (switchChoose)
        {
        case 'A':
            printf("Entering case A...\n");
            printf("Enter product price:\n");
            scanf("%f", &productPrice);

            reajustedPrice = productPrice + (productPrice * 0.03);
            printf("Total price: %.2f", reajustedPrice);
            break;

        case 'D':
            printf("Entering case D...\n");
            printf("Enter product price:\n");
            scanf("%f", &productPrice);

            reajustedPrice = productPrice - (productPrice * 0.03);
            printf("Total price: %.2f", reajustedPrice);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor Pedro evite coloca link de código na pergunta.

Comment: Note que você pede para informar YES ou NOT mas lê um único caractere (e não 3). Em C isto: (operationChoose == 'YES') é imválido, o caractere ' delimita um único caractere e não uma string. Para comparar strings você tem que utilizar a função strcmp de <string.h> e delimitar as strings constantes com " e não '.

Comment: poderia me dar um exemplo de como ficaria o codigo fazendo isso que vc me explicou? uso o #include <string.h>, e depis?? obg!